# Unable to start minikube with Hyper V

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to start minikube on my machine but it gives an error :

```
 Error: [VBOX_NOT_FOUND] create: precreate: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
```

When I installed VirtualBox then and tried to start minikube it says that VirtualBox and Hyper V in conflict. So what is the way to get it started?

Should I disable Hyper V and install VirtualBox or is there a way to use Hyper V ?

Comment: I assume you use it on Windows machine. How do you start your minikube ? What command and what options/flags do you use ? As you can see here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/#install-kubectl on Windows minikube supports both `Virtualbox` and `Hyper-v` so you need to choose between those two hypervisors.

Comment: I am using windows 10 and using minikube start command. But it does not start. Hyper-v is already enabled.

Comment: And when you provide additional flag `--vm-driver hyperv` ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. OK, so if it resolved your issue, let me post it as an official answer to your question so it can be accepted and easily found by other users who may encounter similar problem in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: [VBOX_NOT_FOUND] create: precreate: VBoxManage not found. Make
>   sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path

means that **Minikube** tries to start using the **default hypervisor** which is **Virtualbox** ([ref](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/28/running-kubernetes-locally-on-linux-with-minikube-now-with-kubernetes-1.14-support/)) and it is looking for `VBoxManage` command in your system's `PATH` environment variable which of course is not present there if **VirtualBox** is not installed.

When you want to use a different **hypervisor** ( and you can do it as **Minikube** for **Windows** also supports **Hyper-V** ( [ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) ) you need to provide additional flag to `minikube start` command, specifying the virtualization technology that you want it to use. If you want it to use **Hyper-V**, it should look like this:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
```

Additionally you may want to set `hyper` as your **default driver**. You can do it with the following command:

```
minikube config set vm-driver hyperv
```

You can also find this information [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/hyperv/).